# Setup database context using .NET Core 6.0 from appsetting.json file

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am working on an application where I need to add migrations but it says unable to add migrations. I am registering `startup.cs` but `CreateDefaultBuilder` doesn't contain definition of `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`.

Here is my code:

```
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .Build();

using var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
    .Build();
```

It is a console application. In the `startup` class I am registering `dbContext` like this:

```
collection.AddDbContext<DataScrapperContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

How to use code-first approach to add migrations using console application in .NET Core 6.0?

Answer (score 2):

I have resolve my problem by doing like this. I didn't go with startup class here is my code and my register class and it work like a charm. My **program.cs** consist of the following code.

```
//Build configuration instance
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .Build();

//Build logger for the app
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
          .CreateLogger();

//Create host & configure services to use in the app
using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
   .UseSerilog()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.ConfigureApplicationServices(configuration);
    })
   .Build();
```

Here is my **ConfigureApplicationServices** class code. I have also configure **Serilog** in between.

```
public static class ApplicationService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Registering all the application services with our DI container
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="collection"></param>
        /// <param name="configuration"></param>
        public static void ConfigureApplicationServices(this IServiceCollection collection, IConfiguration configuration)
        {

            #region [SERVICES REGISTERATIONs]
            collection.AddSingleton(configuration);
            collection.AddScoped<ICoordinateService, CoordinateService>();
            collection.AddScoped<IResponseService, ResponseService>();
            collection.AddScoped<RestClientService>();
            collection.AddScoped<CoordinatesProccessor>();
            #endregion

            collection.AddDbContext<DataScrapperContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        }
    }
```

I have added my migrations with code first approach. Might this will be helpful for someone using console application with .NET Core 6.0.